# Map between localizations induces map on underlying modules for Zariski covering

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

While working through a proof of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04148.pdf) paper,<sup>1</sup> at the middle of page 45, the author's claim of a short exact sequence seems to amount to the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $s,t\in A$ which generate the unit ideal. Suppose also that $M,N$ are modules over $A$.
>
> Suppose that we have maps between the localizations
>   $$
> f_s:M_s\rightarrow N_s
> $$
>   $$f_t:M_t\rightarrow N_t$$
>   $$f_{st}:M_{st}\rightarrow N_{st}
> $$
>   such that the diagram
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   $$\begin{CD}
>  M_s @>f_s  > > N_s\\
>  @V  V V @V  V V\\
>  M_{st} @>  >f_{st} > N_{st}
> \end{CD}$$
>   and the analogous one for $t$ commute.
>
> Does there exist a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ making all the relevant diagrams commute?

I thought that applying the theory of the faithfully flat descent for $A\rightarrow A_{s}\times A_{t}$ could be a good idea here but led me nowhere.

<sup>1</sup>Bhargav Bhatt, Jacob Lurie: *A Riemann-Hilbert correspondence in positive characteristic*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04148

Comment: Yes: this is just the fact that if you have a morphism of sheaves defined on each element of an open cover such that restrictions to overlaps are compatible, you can patch together to form a genuine morphism.

Comment: The same question on MathOverflow: [Map between localizations induces map on underlying modules for Zariski covering](https://mathoverflow.net/q/331547). I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice on [meta-tag:cross-posting]. (The most relevant point being that each copy should have links to the other ones.)